# Dynamically add width paramter to url

Tags: javascript, html

I have an url. Let's assume it always looks like this (from server): `https://testurl.com/w/img=67dj455j8j`.

As you can see there's `w` parameter. Undefined, just like above, it returns the image with a standard value for the width. Having `w_700: https://testurl.com/w_700/img=67dj455j8j` would return the image with a width of `700px` though.

How can I dynamically change that parameter programmatically on client side? And what's the best width (ux & bandwidth wise) in regard to the screen size? 1:1?

Comment: var width = "700";
var url = "https://testurl.com/w_" + width + "/img=67dj455j8j";

Comment: are you programming the server or the client?

Comment: @Argee client, using angular - forgot to mention

Comment: What the best width is related to the screen is a matter of opinion/usecase. However you can use `window.innerWidth` to get the width of the current frame if you want it to be the same as the frame. That should work fine together with mplungjan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```js
const width = 800;
const re = /\/w(_\d+)?/;
const url1 = new URL("https://testurl.com/w/img=67dj455j8j");
const url2 = new URL("https://testurl.com/w_700/img=67dj455j8j");

url1.pathname = url1.pathname.replace(re,"\w"+width);
console.log(url1);
url2.pathname = url2.pathname.replace(re,"\w"+width);
console.log(url2);
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the purpose of `re = /\/w(_\d+)?/` - why not just `re = /w`?

Comment: Because you may already may have w_400 and you want to change that too. Also /w would change the w in https://testurl.com/whatfolder/w/ - and \/w is escaped in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('/w/', '/w_700/')
```